# OAuth API doesn't send refresh token with custom redirect_uri

Tags: rest-api, oauth, oauth2, remote-access

If I put this link in my web browser (I put them on separate lines for readability):

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=token
&client_id=MY_CONSUMER_KEY
&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success
```

and log in, it redirects me to the redirect_uri appended with a hash of all the important information I need. I want to use my own redirect_uri, so I modified the callback URL field for the application, and modified my request:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=token
&client_id=MY_CONSUMER_KEY
&redirect_uri=MY_CUSTOM_URI
```

I can log in like I would in the previous example, and it redirects me correctly to my custom uri, **but** without the refresh token in the hash. Any ideas?

Comment: is there a subsequent redirect happening on your side? (eg HTTPS to HTTP, or stripping of WWW subdomain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm):

> The refresh token for the user-agent flow is only issued under one of the following circumstances:
>
> - The redirect URL uses a custom protocol.
> - The redirect URL is exactly
>     https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success, or on Sandbox,
>     https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success.
> - The redirect URL uses the http protocol and the host is localhost - e.g. `http://localhost:8080/`

[User-agent flow](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm) is not intended for use with web apps (which is what it looks like you're trying to do). Use [web server flow](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm) instead.

Comment: There is another undocumented case in which the refresh token is returned in user-agent flow, when the callback url uses the http protocol and the host is localhost.

Comment: Good call, @xn. - added `http://localhost:port/` - thanks!

Comment: @metadaddy when I tried https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token
&client_id=MY_ClientId
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080/  with MY_ClientId replaced with the consumer key and  https://localhost:8080/  as callback url  in browser  below error coming   error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration   what could be the possible reason?

Comment: @ShebinMathew There is often some latency when changing redirect URI - see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12248/67

Comment: @xn too bad it doesn't work when using a self-signed certificate locally on https (i.e. https://localhost)