# OAuth - URL No Longer Exists

Tags: oauth

I am an ISV partner of SalesForce.com,

I use OAuth between my Google App Engine service and my service on Force.com platform to transfer data.

For some reason the handshake of OAuth needs to be repeated many times in-order for it to work.

The steps I take are:
1. Creating a RemoteAccess 
2. Entering the consumer key + secret to my Google App Engine page.
3. Being forwarded to SalesForce.com to enter username+password.

And then, instead of being directed back to Google App Engine to finish the handshake
I get "URL No Longer Exists" in SalesForce.com

Repeating this step a few times few hours later always solves the issue.

I wonder, does the remote access takes time to initialize?
Did you encounter this issue?

**Solution:  SalesForce.com Set a Proper Message When Creating a Remote Access (here it is)**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is some latency; the metadata for Remote Access apps (currently being renamed Connected Apps) takes a few minutes to propagate around the Salesforce servers. I always go make a cup of tea after creating or modifying a Connected App before I test it.

Comment: I am not surprised. In my case it can take more than a cup of tea :), sometimes it takes a few hours...